# Calculating PI recursively in C

Tags: c, recursion, pi

I understand there are probably much better ways of calculating PI, but since I found the Leibniz formula:

[image]
I decided to implement it in C using recursion:

```
double pi(int n){
    if(n==1)return 4;
    return 4*pow(-1,n+1)*(1/(2*n-1))+pi(n-1);
}
```

What I always get when I call the function is just 4.000000, meaning it works for number 1 only; Every other number gives me the same result.

What I'm wondering is why this solution isn't working properly. I've tried writing every step down on paper for different numbers and the logic behind it seems correct.

EDIT:
Except for what was provided in the answer (thank you!) it seems like (1/(double)(2*n-1)) instead of just (1/(2*n-1)) fixed the problem as well.

Comment: this formula doen not fit into recursible algorithm, use iteration, not recursion

Comment: BTW using such expression like `pow()` is extremely in-optimal

Comment: Unfortunately, since I'm taking algorithms and data structure, this is something I have to know how to do using recursion. I've decided that this formula would probably be the best to implement. I'd be glad if I wouldn't ever have to use recursion except for web scraping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is entirely in this term:

```
(1/(2*n-1))
```

Say that n happens to be `3` in this iteration:

```
1 / (2 * 3 - 1) == 1 / 5 == 0
```

*(I'll let you figure out why the result is 0, when you think it should be 0.2)*

---

***Hint #1:*** What is the difference between `1.0` and `1`?

***Hint #2:***  How can you fix the expression by adding just a single character to the expression: `.`??

> `1` has type `int`, `1.0` has type `double`
>  Change the expression to be `(1./(2*n-1))`

Comment: You should at least given a hint :)

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. Changed it to (1/(double)(2*n-1)), it works now.