# how to calculate pi recursively in python?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, recursion, math

Well, I searched a lot to find a solution to calculating pi recursively in python, but i did not find any solution on entire stackoverflow and internet, Although I found a solution for C language in [Calculating PI recursively in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435051/calculating-pi-recursively-in-c)

```
double pi(int n){
if(n==1)return 4;
return 4*pow(-1,n+1)*(1/(double)(2*n-1)))+pi(n-1);
}
```

**As I know nothing about c language and how it's syntax is, I wanted to ask how can I do the same in python3.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pi calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284996/python-pi-calculation)

Comment: @NickReed, I already have gone through these posts on stack  overflow and the post your are pointing at, is using for loop

Comment: You don't know anything about c, on, but this is almost the same as python. What's troubling you?

Comment: @NickReed, because there were no recursion in any of the solutions, I was made to post this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-written in python:

```
def get_pi(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 4
    return 4 * (-1)**(n+1) * (1/(2*n-1)) + get_pi(n-1)
```